# in phpmailer_init the argument 'to' is null

Tags: wordpress, email, hook

I'm trying to hook into phpmailer_init. I'm using this code:

```
function bp_emails($result, $to, $cc, $bcc, $subject, $body) {
    $email_to = $to;
    $email_body = $body;
    $email_subject = $subject;    
    }
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', function( $phpmailer )
{
    $phpmailer->action_function = 'bp_emails';
} );
```

in the code above $email_body and $email_subject is ok But $email_to is always null. Can you help me find the proper value for $email_to?

Answer (score 0):

Please read this:

1. Action Reference/[phpmailer_init](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init)
2. phpmailer_init declared in [pluggable.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/pluggable.php)
3. [PHPMailer class](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php)

So the code should be:

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'bp_emails' );
function bp_emails( $phpmailer ) {
    $email_to = $phpmailer->getAllRecipientAddresses(); // array
    $email_body = $phpmailer->Body;
    $email_subject = $phpmailer->Subject;
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jared-chu for your reply. I tried your answer but there are some problems here:1. When I try to add_action in this way, the action is not working at all. 2. $phpmailer->to is still giving null value